# Varnish always 301 redirecting

Tags: wordpress, apache, varnish, varnish-vcl

I've got an apache running wordpress on port 90. I've put a varnish cache in front of it and am running varnish on port 80.

I'm using the 4.0 vcl from here: https://github.com/nicolargo/varnish-nginx-wordpress/blob/master/varnish/varnish4-wordpress

When I request my site on :80 I get 301 redirected to :90 ... Surely that's not the point of varnish? How do I avoid this and stay on :80??

I'm a complete newbie to varnish / vcl so I unfortunately have no idea what to look for. I'm sure it's in the VCL though :)

Related post (but not answer on here either): [Why is Varnish redirecting as 301?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480807/why-is-varnish-redirecting-as-301)

Answer (score 1):

It is surely not in VCL. However, do note that it's much better to start building from the provided `default.vcl`, adding bits by bits, to understand how it works.

As for why it doesn't work and ways to fix it.

#### Different ports (duh).

**Option #1. Tell your PHP what the real port is**.

Perhaps, *the* most easy fix would be to edit `wp-config.php` and tell the Wordpress where the request really came from. Add at the top of the file right after `<?php`:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 80;
```

**Option #2. Just use the same ports.**

You can actually use *same* port number(!) in both Varnish and Apache. Simply bind Varnish and Apache onto different interfaces, but same port numbers. To a Linux machine those are different ports, and there is no issue using same port number.

So Apache will have:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

Varnish will have in the VCL:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80";
}
```

**Option #3. Don't use Apache. Nginx to the rescue.**

A not so easy fix perhaps would be switching to Nginx which can easily circumvent the "port in redirection" problem via simply one line of configuration:

```
port_in_redirect off;
```

#### Wordpress base URLs.

If the Wordpress site URL (in wp-admin) is set to include port number, then naturally that's where it will redirect you. No port number should be present in Wordpress site URL.

Bonus Tip: [Fix Wordpress Jetpack in Varnish](https://www.getpagespeed.com/troubleshooting/varnish-and-jetpack-error-503-backend-fetch-failed).

Comment: "You can actually use same port number(!) in both Varnish and Apache." Nope, you're setting the `backend` which is the source content from which Varnish will pull from. Changing the Varnish port is done through something like `/etc/sysconfig/varnish` or through the startup script

Comment: @DonWilson what "Nope"? :) I was mentioning "different interfaces". Which means that if you have Varnish set to listen on *only* 1.2.3.4 (your external IP) and port 80, you can *still* have Apache listen on 127.0.0.1 and port 80. Because essentially those are different ports (since they are on different interfaces)